# Launching a heavy use web app with shiny r

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, shinydashboard

I am finally ready to release my shiny web application. I will be driving some serious load to it(about 1000-2000 people). I am using shinyapps.io. My question is, will async programming be necessary? shinyapps.io seem to have some pretty customizable features in regards to how many instances to launch.

The app will be doing a few very simple for loops on a data frame of 20 x 1000. There will be 3 plots and one data frame. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Its not straight forward to scale the app for this many people. If you have full control over the linux box you can create other R processes to cater for that (similar set-up as the one outlined in Rstudio website about scalability). Alternitavely I would suggest re-writing into as a RMarkdown or FlexDashboard without the shiny component where the end users simply download the page

Comment: I need the reactivity shiny provides @PorkChop. I got in touch with the Rstudio support team, and they said I should be able to scale to that level quite easily. Still skeptical tho. If i do a load test and it works, can I assume that it will be good in real life?